# Yet another selenium question (driver.find_element_by_css_selector)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get string:

> Liquidity (Including Fees)

from line

```
<div class="sc-bdVaJa KpMoH css-1ecm0so">Liquidity (Including Fees)</div>
```

I've tried these below
none of them gave me the string that I want:

```
usdbaslik = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[class='sc-bdVaJa KpMoH css-1ecm0so']")
print(usdbaslik.text,":---text")
print(usdbaslik.tag_name,":---tag_name")
print(usdbaslik.id,":---id")
print(usdbaslik.size,":---size")
print(usdbaslik.rect,":---rect")
print(usdbaslik.location,":---location")
print(usdbaslik.location_once_scrolled_into_view,":---location_once_scrolled_into_view")
print(usdbaslik.parent,":---parent")
print(usdbaslik.screenshot_as_png,":--screenshot_as_png")
print(usdbaslik.screenshot_as_base64,":--screenshot_as_base64")
print(usdbaslik.__class__,":--__class__")
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share URL so that we can try?

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sc-bdVaJa.KpMoH.css-1ecm0so")`

Comment: Sure

https://info.pangolin.exchange/#/account/0x84d34f4f83a87596cd3fb6887cff8f17bf5a7b83

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (at least) one other element with that class on the page, so it's not a unique selector. The closest thing I was able to find to a unique selector looking at the page would be

```
usdbaslik = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="sc-VigVT fKQdIL"]//div[@class="sc-bdVaJa KpMoH css-1ecm0so"]')[0])
```

Then you can get the text from the label with

```
print(usdbaslik.get_attribute('innerText'))
```